# How to prevent React app build from being cached?

Tags: reactjs, web, webpack, create-react-app, browser-cache

I have created a React app using create react app. Whenever I deploy a new build, the changes don't reflect since the browser has cached the build files. How do i ensure that each new build is not cached?

Is there some way to do this? Like configuring the build command to generate new filenames on each build?

Comment: If you're running [a production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/), the assets are hashed to help with enabling (and busting) cache. Do you have a long cache-control set on your index.html?

Comment: @ZacAnger I haven't set any cache control in index.html. If everytime the hash is new then why are the files being cached in the first place?

Comment: They shouldn't be, that's why I asked if your index.html has a long cache-control response header. If you run a build, look at the generated filenames, change something, run another build, and compare, they'll be different. Anything else in front of your app that could be caching?

Comment: Please share the code of webpack.config.js file?

Comment: @NikhilG I don't have any webpack config setup. Can i setup some config that would work?

Comment: @ZacAnger the build hashes generated are different, but i noticed that post deployment the build hash in index.html was different from the build hash I got after building locally. After i cleared cache i could see the same build hash in index.html that i got locally. Also i see that in the size column of network tab, it showed 'service worker' before clearing the cache. Could this be something related to service workers?

Comment: The [default SW doesn't do anything](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js#L17). If you added one yourself, it's possible. Are you refreshing with shift to clear browser cache, or doing some other browsing between refreshing? Browsers don't always automatically refetch. And in the network tab, what's value of the cache-control header on the response?

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks it's resolved now. We had added some SW code to convert the app into the PWA. It also had some part that was caching the index.html.